# sql - split string to separate columns and drop values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query -

```
select um.usrmst_name 'ITAM Owner',
       wg.workgrp_name 'TIDAL Workgroup',
       isnull(jm.jobmst_prntname, '') + '\' + jm.jobmst_name 'Job'
       from jobmst jm
inner join workgrp wg on wg.workgrp_id = jm.jobmst_owner
inner join usrmst um on um.usrmst_id = wg.workgrp_owner
where jm.jobmst_active = 'Y' and jm.jobmst_dirty != 'X' and um.usrmst_domain = 'ITAM'
```

It returns a result like this:

```
| ITAM Owner | TIDAL Workgroup | Job
| CORE       | Sage-Talcura    | \Sage-Talcura
| CORE       | Sage-Talcura    | \Sage-Talcura\1.0 Import Sage-Talcura Data
```

How I want it to look like is this:

```
| ITAM Owner | TIDAL Workgroup | Job Group     | Job
| CORE       | Sage-Talcura    | \Sage-Talcura | 1.0 Import Sage-Talcura Data
```

How would I revise my query to acheive this result?  I've tried doing a case as well as a convoluted substring left/right which I still can't get (the LEFT) to work:

```
select um.usrmst_name 'ITAM Owner',
       wg.workgrp_name 'TIDAL Workgroup',
       ISNULL(jm.jobmst_prntname, '') + '\' + jm.jobmst_name,
       -- left(isnull(jm.jobmst_prntname, '') + '\' + jm.jobmst_name, len(isnull(jm.jobmst_prntname, '') + '\' + jm.jobmst_name) - charindex('\',reverse(isnull(jm.jobmst_prntname, '') + '\' + jm.jobmst_name))) 'Job Group',
       right((isnull(jm.jobmst_prntname, '') + '\' + jm.jobmst_name), charindex('\', reverse(isnull(jm.jobmst_prntname, '') + '\' + jm.jobmst_name)) -1) 'Job'
       from jobmst jm
inner join workgrp wg on wg.workgrp_id = jm.jobmst_owner
inner join usrmst um on um.usrmst_id = wg.workgrp_owner
where jm.jobmst_active = 'Y'
  and jm.jobmst_dirty != 'X'
  and um.usrmst_domain = 'ITAM'
  and (isnull(jm.jobmst_prntname, '') + '\' + jm.jobmst_name like '\%\%')
```

Comment: You would start by providing some details in your question. Like some sample data and table structure. Also using string literals as aliases is not a practice at all. It is really challenging to decipher your code. See #6 on the list of poor alias patterns here. https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases

Comment: You are concatenating two columns and then trying to split them. Why you do not remove rows where jm.jobmst_prntname is null and show columns separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case when CHARINDEX('\',Job,2)=0 then Job else left(Job,CHARINDEX('\',Job,2)-1) end 'Job Group',
case when CHARINDEX('\',Job,2)>1 then SUBSTRING(Job,CHARINDEX('\',Job,2)+1,999) end 'Job'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.. GROUP BY and MAX.

```
select um.usrmst_name 'ITAM Owner',
       wg.workgrp_name 'TIDAL Workgroup',
       isnull(jm.jobmst_prntname, '') [Job Group],
       MAX(jm.jobmst_name) 'Job'
       from jobmst jm
inner join workgrp wg on wg.workgrp_id = jm.jobmst_owner
inner join usrmst um on um.usrmst_id = wg.workgrp_owner
where jm.jobmst_active = 'Y' and jm.jobmst_dirty != 'X' and um.usrmst_domain = 'ITAM'
GROUP BY um.usrmst_name, wg.workgrp_name ,isnull(jm.jobmst_prntname, '')
```